# Change/Remap find shortcut in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm a new user of iTerm2.
Recently I change the keybindings that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>B</kbd>) as the Bash keybindings via the **iTerm2** > **Preferences** > **Key Bindings**.

However, in this setting, I can't search the text from the Terminal by the default keybinding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Is there any way to *change/modify* the **Find keybindings** to other keybindings or a better way to search the text with the shortcut keybindings?

(I had checked the document [keys](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-keys.html), but it looks like can't set the find shortcut.)

Comment: I guess the question would be *Why did you change them in the first place?  What were you trying to accomplish?*

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I want to use the space CMD+F (the same in the Linux ALT+F) to move my bash cursor by the word. But after I change the action CMD+F to ESC+F(ALT+F). I can't search the iTerm with the shortcut keybindings. So I want to search some way to alternate the Search keybindings in iTerm.

Comment: Set them to something that isn't overriding what your shell expects.

Comment: You just said that you changed them, not *why* you changed them. Search in iTerm is not a Bash function; it’s a function of the terminal emulator (iTerm) which is a macOS app.   You search the scrollback buffer which is part of the terminal app, not Bash.

Comment: @MarcWilson I want to keep the same keystroke both in Linux and MacOS. So it will overriding the default keybinding in the iTerm.

Comment: @Allan I changed them because I want to use the same keystroke in Linux for move the text in the bash shell. And I also want to use the search function in the terminal emulator like in the iTerm, and gonme-termianl. So, I didn't change the search function for the bash shell.

Comment: Thank you all guys that try to revise my question and figure out my question. Now, I maybe use the `Shift`+`Cmd`+`F` for alternative for the search function on the iTerm until one day I find a good way to share with.

Comment: Bash in macOS uses the same same keybindings as in Linux (unless changed there).  For example, `Ctrl-A` moves to the beginning of the line in the shell in macOS and Linux.  If you’re talking about the GUI, like searching the scrollback buffer, I suggest getting used to macOS keyboard shortcuts - you’ll have less headaches.

Comment: @Allan yes, it is the same Ctrl+A/E/F/B/U/K as in Linux. But in the Linux will use the Alt+B/F to move backward/forword by word.

Comment: Those are *shell* keybindings.  It’s not related to Linux but to the Bash/Zsh shells you’re using

Comment: Yes, perhaps I need to clarify more specific to avoid any misunderstandings. I want to keep the same keybindings in bash as default setting and both in the same keystroke  for Linux/MacOS.